# Powershell - Compiling with Modules

Tags: powershell, module, compilation, active-directory

I have created a log-on script based on Active-Directory Module, that queries the user group membership in order to map his drives etc.

I have compiled it with PowerGui, and created an EXE file.
the problem is, the module doesn't exist on the users computers.

Is there a way to do this without the module, or add the module to the compilation?

Comment: Why not call them from your DC or \\Domain\Sysvol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For group memberships, you could also get it without connecting to AD, and parse the output of the WHOAMI utility

```
$groups = WHOAMI /GROUPS /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Group Name'

if($groups -contains 'group1')
{
   do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**One way is using Active-Directory Service Interface (ADSI)**.

you can find in another SO post ([Can I match a user to a group accross different domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794945/608772)) one way to find all the groups a user belongs to, using ADSI, in the post it's a C# code, but it's easy to translate.

Here is a small example of a simple search to begin.

```
Clear-Host
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr","jpb@dom.fr","Pwd")

# Look for a user
$user2Find = "user1"
$Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$rc = $Rech.filter = "((sAMAccountName=$user2Find))"
$rc = $Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

$theUser = $Rech.FindOne()
if ($theUser -ne $null)
{
  Write-Host $theUser.Properties["mail"]
}
```

**Another way is to use [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299745.aspx).**

This way is also using ADSI, but it's encapsulated, and you need the Framework .NET 3.5. You will also find in the [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794945/608772) but in the Edited *(2011-10-18 13:25)* part, a C# code using this way.

**You can also use WMI :**

```
$user2Find = "user1"
$query = "SELECT * FROM ds_user where ds_sAMAccountName='$user2find'"
$user = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -Namespace "root\Directory\LDAP"
$user.DS_mail
```

You can use this solution localy on your server or from a computer inside the domain, but it's a bit more complicated to authenticate to WMI from outside the domain.